# shared functionality in mocha tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I put the following code in its own file called `shared.js`

```
afterEach(function () {
  // insert code 
});

var foo;

beforeEach(function () {
  foo = {
    bar: []
  };
});

exports = module.exports = {};
exports.foo = foo;
```

I'd like the `afterEach` and `beforeEach` to be ran in every mocha.js test I have. so in each test file, I required `shared.js`.

The problem is it seems `foo` isn't available in the scope of my tests. `foo.bar` is undefined and inaccessible. The `beforeEach()` and `afterEach` hooks are running just fine, but I'm having trouble understanding how to properly export the scope of `foo`. This might be more of a Node.js problem than an actual Mocha problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can not modify the exported reference. In your case you are exporting `undefined`, because foo is uninitialized. If you initialize `foo` with an empty object and later try to reassign it to a different thing/object it will still not work because the exported reference is still the same.

The only thing you can do is modifying (mutating) the exported object like so:

```
afterEach(function () {
  // insert code 
});

var foo = {};

beforeEach(function () {
  foo.bar = [];
});

exports = module.exports = {};
exports.foo = foo;
```

Comment: should `foo.bar` ultimately be available then in any file I `require` this in? Because I'm trying to `foo.bar.push({});` in my test that requires this shared file and I get `foo is not defined`

Comment: @randombits You need to assign the require result to a variable to be able to access the exported data. e.g. `var shared = require("./shared");` then you can access foo in your module via `shared.foo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is specific to the context of each test, you can do something like the following:

```
afterEach(function () {
  // insert code 
});

beforeEach(function () {
  this.foo = [];
});

exports = module.exports = {};
```

each test can then access its own `this.foo`:

```
describe('myTest', function() {
  it('should do something', function() {
    this.foo.push("1"); // same 'this' as from beforeEach
    // ...insert code
  })
})
```